# How to refer to the true 'body' of a page? [NOT iFrame body]

Tags: javascript

I have a script that create a new div element. Then, I want to append the div to the body of the page using appendChild method.

The script is look like this :

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'newdiv';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Unfortunately, the div also appended to the body of iframes. So, my question is, how to refer to the true body of the document, not including the body of the iframes? That way, the div just appended once, to the "true body" of the document. Thanks before, and sorry if my english is bad. :-D

EDIT:

This happens at Mozilla Firefox browser. I haven't tested it at any other browsers yet. And another information, this is a GreaseMonkey script I try to develop.

Comment: Under which browser does that happen? (By the way, 4 spaces at the beginning of a line means 'this is source code' in Stack Overflow's formatting scheme; please trim your text if you want it to be well-formatted.)

Comment: Sorry, i added that by accident. It's happening at Firefox, should I add this information to my question description?

Comment: @Jim: Yes, you should. Could you also provide a sample of code where this happens? I can hardly see how it could.

Comment: I'd love a link to the doc where this is happening. I'm 99% sure what you describe isn't possible.

Comment: @zneak: The code is exactly like the above example I wrote, with some modification on the innerHTML

Comment: @Jim: What about the HTML then? Can you show us the `<iframe>` tag and tell us the file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

top.document.body.appendChild(div); //maybe?