# Finding first node of a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('body').append('<div id="popupContact"><a id="popupContactClose">close</a><br/><iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe></div><div id="backgroundPopup"></div>');
```

I tested it at [this](http://naver.com) site.

It worked but I have a problem. I think that the site has many iframes, so I want to find the first body of the combined page. I tried this code.

```
$('body')[0].append('<div id="popupContact"><a id="popupContactClose">close</a><br/><iframe src="http://google.com/" id = myFrame></iframe></div><div id="backgroundPopup"></div>');
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work.

I want to apply the rule only to the first body tag.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Don't know if this applies here, but if the iframes are not coming from the same domain, you cannot access their content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `$('body:first')`. See http://api.jquery.com/first-selector for details.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('body').first();
```

Or this:

```
$('iframe').first();
```

Comment: Then you can do this:
`$('iframe').first().append('<div id="popupContact"><a id="popupContactClose">close</a><br/><iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe></div><div id="backgroundPopup"></div>');`

Comment: If I understand jQuery performance correctly, this will be slower than $('body:first'), as it has to search for all 'body' nodes before picking the first of these.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this too, but found that both $('body:first') and $('body').first() still grabbed the first node of each iframe on the page.

Essentially what I was trying to do was add a div. Using top.document.body was what solved the issue for me. As in:

```
top.document.body.appendChild(mydiv);
```

As pointed out on this page, I was looking for the 'true' body of the page:
[How to refer to the true 'body' of a page? [NOT iFrame body]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437148/how-to-refer-to-the-true-body-of-a-page-not-iframe-body)